# Box2D Flash - Perfect Character Collision? (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, box2d

I was wondering if it's possible to get almost perfect character collision with Box2D (Flash)? 
I know the basics of Actionscript 3 but know very little about Box2D. I can create character collision to stop the character running through platforms and such with Actionscript 3 but because the character isn't a simple shape, it's quite glitchy.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, yes. See the interactive ragdoll example right on the [**Box2DFlash homepage**](http://box2dflash.sourceforge.net/). You can download the source code for the examples from the same page to see how they work.